# Contraction of 2 Riemann tensors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

Iz possibile to find a costant $c\neq0$ such that $R^{abcd} R_{cbad} = c R^{abcd}R_{abcd}$?

Comment: I haven't written the problem out and attempted it, but I imagine you will need to use the [symmetries of the Riemann tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Symmetries_and_identities) in some way to move indices around (assuming I've understood the problem, which is a little awkwardly worded).

Answer (score 1):

Use $R_{[abc]d} = 0$ and other symmetries of Riemann tensor.

Comment: yes, but I can get exactly the right order. Have you tried it?